# How to get document id from firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get my every document id in of my collection "meinprofilsettings". But I'm a bit struggling with that so maybe anyone can help.

First here's my code:

```
List<String> alluserids = [];

getHashtags() async {
    final ref = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

    QuerySnapshot snapshots = await ref.collection('meinprofilsettings').get();

    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot idofuser in snapshots.docs) {
      allVideoHastags.addAll(idofuser.id);
    }
}
```

And then here's the error I get:

> The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable'.

This is a screenshot of my database:

[image]

I I just want every id of of every doc inside the list alluserids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

addAll method receives an Iterable as parameter. You want to add a single value so you should use `.add`

Also, you could use the .map method instead of for in:

```dart
allVideoHastags.addAll(snapshots.docs.map((idofuser)=>idofuser.id));
```

The behavior behind the last statement is that map returns an `Iterable` which has a value for each value that the base `Iterable` (in this case, your docs) contains.

In this case, the base iterable is `snapshots.docs` and our mapping returns `Iterable<String>` as we're returning every doc id. Hope this is enough for helping

Comment: ok and how do I check if a string exists with the where ? Do I use araycontains or isEqualTo  or  what I should use ?

Comment: there do you want to check it?

Comment: No I mean like for example when I use something like this  .where(_data[_index].uid, isEqualTo:  allVideoHastags) should I use arayvcontains or isEqualTo or what should I need ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't get it. You could create a new question so you can explain it better

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you want to change this

```
allVideoHastags.addAll(idofuser.id);
```

To this:

```
alluserids.add(idofuser.id);
```